# Does one fulfill their obligation of davening if they leaned on a shtender?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, standing-sitting

I've seen people - in *shul* - leaning on *shtenders* when they are davening *shemoneh esrei*. *Halachichally,* if someone is leaning on his *shtender* while he's davening *shemoneh esrei,* is he יוצא?

Comment: Yo9ei but still sinned for not praying properly

Comment: One is yotzei if sitting

Comment: MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, please explain yourself.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah a person who is not sick or old has to pray a certain way. if he doesnt he has sinned but still yo9ei

Comment: @  שְׁמוֹנָה דְּבָרִים, צָרִיךְ הַמִּתְפַּלֵּל לְהִזָּהֵר בָּהֶן וְלַעֲשׂוֹתָן; וְאִם הָיָה דָּחוּק, אוֹ נֶאֱנָס, אוֹ שֶׁעָבַר וְלֹא עָשָׂה אוֹתָן--אֵינָן מְעַכְּבִין.  וְאֵלּוּ הֶן--עֲמִידָה, וְנֹכַח הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, וְתִקּוּן הַגּוּף, וְתִקּוּן הַמַּלְבּוּשׁ, וְתִקּוּן הַמָּקוֹם, וְהַשְׁוָיַת הַקּוֹל, וְהַכְּרִיעָה, וְהַהִשְׁתַּחֲוָיָה.

Comment: עָבַר .......15

Answer (score 2):

In shulchan aruch siman tzadik daled seif ches יש ליזהר שלא לסמוך עצמו לעמוד... בשעת תפלה you shouldn't lean yourself during davening (shmonah esrei) in mishnah berurah (on this seif) ולכן יזהר שלא יסמוך עצמו ע"ג "שטענדער" therefore you should not lean yourself on a shtender the next seif in shulchan aruch says מי שהוכרח להתפלל מיושב צריך לחזור ולהתפלל מעומד...  one who was forced to daven sitting down has to daven again after standing... in mishnah berurah on that he writes ולדינא... שאינו צריך לחזור ולהתפלל שנית... the halachah at the end (all agree) is that you dont have to daven again

So for sure if you were just "leaning" on a shtender you don't have to daven again and you were yotzeh.

Comment: Can you send me a link to where it is located? Also, what does next week seif mean?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=250 and the next page     Week is a mistake it should just say seif סעיף

Comment: You know you can [edit] your post if you make a mistake.